# DRF, return what's sent by client back along with serializer.data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I save a temporary data in a client and it gets an client-id. 
(App stores user posting data in client until the submission is complete)

I'd like to send this client-id along with other data to the server when creating/updating.

If server can append this client-id when he responds with serializer.data, client can delete the temporary data saved in the client side.

It seems I have to override viewsets's `create/update` and I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: 'temporary data in a client and it has an ID', what is this a session variable?

Comment: It's a unsaved(to server) data which user is writing.

Comment: So it's in the request as you're saving it?

Comment: I save [data, clientId] in client, I want to send [data, clientId] and get back [serializer.data, clientId] back. but clientId is not ordinary field which you can save in server side because it has meaning to the original requester only.

Comment: You're going to need to post some example code, question is difficult to read.

Comment: You can do one thing. Check default code of create/update of drf. If it does not fit your needs, then try overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

One of your options is something like this:

views.py:

```
class PostDataWithClienID(APIView):
    def post(self, request, client_id):

    # Context needed if you need client_id while saving posted data
    serializer = PostedDataSerializer(data=request.data,
                                      context={'client_id': client_id})

    if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'data': serializer.data, 
                             'client_id': client_id}, 
                            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...

    url(r'^/(?P<client_id>[0-9]+)/post_data_with_client_id$', views.PostDataWithClienID.as_view()),
    ...
```

If you want to have it combine in the response, you can do this instead:

```
class PostDataWithClienID(APIView):
    def post(self, request, client_id):

    # Context needed if you need client_id while saving posted data
    serializer = PostedDataSerializer(data=request.data,
                                      context={'client_id': client_id})

    if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            my_response_dict = serializer.data.copy()
            my_response_dict.update({'client_id': client_id})
            return Response(my_response_dict, 
                            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I was hoping to stuff client_id in serializer.data somehow.

Comment: It's not a really good idea. Why do you want to do exactly that? If you want to have it there only in response json - you can combine one dictionary with all the fields. I've updated my answer on how to do this.